# copying values to the next row in time based on a third column in r

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, lag, shift

I'm attempting to create a new column smk_R from the data I have. For each ID variable, I have data of two types over time. Type 1 data are my anchors and will be kept to use for later analysis. The information in Type 0 rows is also important and should be pushed to the next Type 1 row later in time within each ID. Essentially, I am looking to see if people smoked a cigarette between two Type 1 assessments (smk=0 for no and smk=1 for yes). If they did, the next Type 1 assessment should indicate smk_R=1 even if smk=0 at that specific Type 1 assessment. Any thoughts on how to do this would be much appreciated. I don't have the variable grp in my data but if that can be created from dat1, I think I can take the max of smk within group to get smk_R.

```
ID<-c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9)
time<-c(0.16,0.35,0.72,1.17,1.19,1.19,1.65,1.99,2.2,2.37,2.78,3.57,3.88,4.12,0.29,0.35,0.79,1.17,1.29,1.29,1.75,1.96,2.27,2.57,2.78,3.57,4.88,5.12)
type<-c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
smk<-c(1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)
grp<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,6)
smk_R<-c(1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)

dat1<-cbind.data.frame(ID,time,type,smk)
dat1

   ID time type smk
1   5 0.16    0   1
2   5 0.35    1   0
3   5 0.72    0   0
4   5 1.17    1   0
5   5 1.19    0   0
6   5 1.19    1   1
7   5 1.65    0   1
8   5 1.99    0   1
9   5 2.20    0   1
10  5 2.37    0   0
11  5 2.78    0   0
12  5 3.57    1   0
13  5 3.88    1   0
14  5 4.12    1   0
15  9 0.29    0   1
16  9 0.35    1   0
17  9 0.79    0   0
18  9 1.17    1   0
19  9 1.29    0   0
20  9 1.29    1   1
21  9 1.75    0   0
22  9 1.96    0   0
23  9 2.27    0   0
24  9 2.57    0   0
25  9 2.78    0   0
26  9 3.57    1   0
27  9 4.88    1   1
28  9 5.12    1   1

dat2<-cbind.data.frame(dat1,grp,smk_R)
dat2
    ID time type smk grp smk_R
 1   5 0.16    0   1   1     1
 2   5 0.35    1   0   1     1
 3   5 0.72    0   0   2     0
 4   5 1.17    1   0   2     0
 5   5 1.19    0   0   3     1
 6   5 1.19    1   1   3     1
 7   5 1.65    0   1   4     1
 8   5 1.99    0   1   4     1
 9   5 2.20    0   1   4     1
 10  5 2.37    0   0   4     1
 11  5 2.78    0   0   4     1
 12  5 3.57    1   0   4     1
 13  5 3.88    1   0   5     0
 14  5 4.12    1   0   6     1
 15  9 0.29    0   1   1     1
 16  9 0.35    1   0   1     1
 17  9 0.79    0   0   2     0
 18  9 1.17    1   0   2     0
 19  9 1.29    0   0   3     1
 20  9 1.29    1   1   3     1
 21  9 1.75    0   0   4     0
 22  9 1.96    0   0   4     0
 23  9 2.27    0   0   4     0
 24  9 2.57    0   0   4     0
 25  9 2.78    0   0   4     0
 26  9 3.57    1   0   4     0
 27  9 4.88    1   1   5     1
 28  9 5.12    1   1   6     1
```

Comment: You're asking for a pretty specific, confusing task and asking us to write the code for you. Can you boil down your question to exactly where you're running into an issue (i.e. which piece you can't do yourself)?

Comment: @wtrs I added another column that may be an intermediate step. If a new grouping variable can be created from dat1 I could take the max of smk within each group within each ID to get to smk_R. Each time a type = 1 assessment shows up, the previous group ends and a new group starts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The addition in your comment looks like a good approach. Then you could do (for example):

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat1 %>%
  arrange(ID, time, type) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(c(1, type[-n()]))) %>%
  group_by(ID, grp) %>%
  mutate(smk_R = max(smk))

as.data.frame(dat2)
```

Comment: Nice solution ! Maybe `mutate(grp = cumsum(type)+1)` might be less cryptic than `mutate(grp = cumsum(c(1, type[-n()])))`. Also with this solution you don't look only at what is happening between the assignments but also at was is happening at the assignment. If smk is always 0 between the assignments (when type ==0) smk_R will be 1 if smk == 1 at the assignment (when type ==1). This might be correct but the exact result expected by @swhusky is not so clear

Comment: agree, `cumsum(type) + 1` is nicer

Comment: @Gilles that's useful too if each new group started at a Type 1 assignment. From the expected result in the example though, each group ends when a Type 1 assessment shows up which is what RolandASc's answer does.